# Where Should I put the `images` directory in order to use it in css as `/images/...`

Tags: html, resources, build, jsf-2

Using JSF 2.0.
Got an app running with `CSS` and `Javascript` running from `/Servlet/resources/css` and `/Servlet/resources/js` accordingly.

I would like to add an images folder so I can refer to the images from the css file as `/images/file.jpg`.
Where should I place the `images` folder.

Alternatively, How would I refer to the images if they were places in the `/Servlet/resources/` directory?

Tnx!

Comment: Then that would be the folders above the CSS file `../images/file.jpg` will use the root of the virtual directory. If you want to use `/images/file.jpg` then you directory sturcture must look like `/Servlet/resources/css/images/file.jpg` but if you will refer to the same image from the JS direcotry you will have a problem..

Comment: @ppumkin Tnx. why don't you paste it into an answer so I could mark it as such? :-)

Comment: not sure- i started out with a comment and landed up with an answer :D hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the folders above the CSS file.

```
 /Servlet/resources/css/images/file.jpg
```

but if you will refer to the same image from the JS direcotry you will have a problem.

Instead you could try and use (not sure what your virtual root directory but usually you would use)

```
../images/file.jpg
```

links in the same directory as the page have no path information listed
 **file.jpg**

sub-directories are listed without any preceding slashes  **images/file.jpg**

links up one directory are listed as **../file.jpg**

Answer (score 2):

I'd put CSS background images in a separate folder in the CSS folder:

```
/Servlet/resources/css/images/*
```

This way you can reference them as follows in your CSS without fiddling too much with relative path:

```
background-image: url('images/foo.png');
```

---

As to normal images which you reference by HTML `<img>` and on (but not by CSS), I'd put them in the following folder

```
/Servlet/resources/images/*
```